# JPA query validation fails at subselect even though it is working in console

Tags: spring, validation, jpa, spring-data, jpql

**Situation:**

I have got the following jpa query which works flawlessly in the IntelliJ jpa-ql console. I've added it as picture so one can see the code highlighting and therefore the actual error:

```
select 
    run1.someAttribute1 AS someAttribute1, 
    run1.someAttribute2 AS someAttribute2, 
    run1.someAttribute3 AS someAttribute3, 
    (select
        sum(function('timestampdiff', SECOND, run2.runStartTime, run2.runEndTime)) 
        from runTable AS run2 
        where run2.anotherAttribute1 = run1.anotherAttribute1 
        and run2.anotherAttribute2 = run1.someAttribute2 
        and run2.anotherAttribute3 = run1.someAttribute3
    ) AS runtime, 
    sum(
        case when type(event) = SomeEvent and event.someType = '...' then 1   
        else 0 end
    ) AS numberOfSomething1,
    sum(
        case when type(event) = SomeEvent and event.someType = '...' then 1     
        else 0 end
    ) AS numberOfSomething2, 
    sum(
        case when type(event) = SomeEvent and event.someType = '...' then 1 
        else 0 end
    ) AS numberOfSomething3, 
    sum(
        case when type(event) = SomeEvent and event.someType = '...' then 1 
        else 0 end
    ) AS numberOfSomething4, 
    sum(
        case when type(event) = SomeEvent2 then 1 
        else 0 end
    ) AS numberOfSomething5from runTable AS run1 
left join run1.events AS event 
group by someAttribute1, someAttribute2, someAttribute3 
order by 
    max(function('right', function('left', someAttribute1, 8), 3)) desc,    
    someAttribute2 desc, 
    someAttribute3 desc
```

[JPA Query with subselect validation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7XMt.png)

If ran in the jpa-ql console it returns the following result:

[Right result with sub select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkLGZ.png)

The third column is the runTime in seconds which is correct if done with the subselect query. If I refactor the subselect to use the run1 alias it returns the wrong result. I thought the grouping does already contain the right runTime but obviously I'm wrong:

```
select 
    run1.someAttribute1 AS someAttribute1, 
    run1.someAttribute2 AS someAttribute2, 
    run1.someAttribute3 AS someAttribute3, 
    sum(
       function('timestampdiff', SECOND, run1.runStartTime, run1.runEndTime)
    ) AS runtime, 
    sum(case when type(event) = SomeEvent and event.someType = '...' then 1 else 0 end) AS numberOfSomething1,
    sum(case when type(event) = SomeEvent and event.someType = '...' then 1 else 0 end) AS numberOfSomething2, 
    sum(case when type(event) = SomeEvent and event.someType = '...' then 1 else 0 end) AS numberOfSomething3, 
    sum(case when type(event) = SomeEvent and event.someType = '...' then 1 else 0 end) AS numberOfSomething4, 
    sum(case when type(event) = SomeEvent2 then 1 else 0 end) AS numberOfSomething5from runTable AS run1 
left join run1.events AS event 
group by someAttribute1, someAttribute2, someAttribute3 
order by max(function('right', function('left', someAttribute1, 8), 3)) desc,
    someAttribute2 desc, 
    someAttribute3 desc
```

[Wrong result with alias from the FROM clause](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaVIy.png)

**Problem**

The main difference is, that the first jpa query throws an error while starting up the spring boot application, while the refactored one does not:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List someClass.someMethod()
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:92) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.8.RELEASE.jar:?]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:62) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.8.RELEASE.jar:?]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:72) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.8.RELEASE.jar:?]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromQueryAnnotation(JpaQueryFactory.java:53) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.8.RELEASE.jar:?]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.8.RELEASE.jar:?]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:211) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.8.RELEASE.jar:?]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:77) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.8.RELEASE.jar:?]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:436) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.8.RELEASE.jar:?]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:221) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.8.RELEASE.jar:?]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:277) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.8.RELEASE.jar:?]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:263) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.8.RELEASE.jar:?]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:101) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.8.RELEASE.jar:?]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
... 17 more
```

It seems like spring data can't handle the opening bracket which follows a comma within the select clause(see [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7XMt.png)), even though the actual query does work.

**Question**

Is there any way to solve this issue or rewrite the subselect query?

Used spring-data version 1.11.8 which does the query validation

Comment: The stacktrace should include more lines, especially a "caused by" please let us see that as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you executed in the console but it's neither of the queries you posted, which becomes obvious once you format them as I did.

In both cases, there is a space missing in front of the `from` before the `left join`.

Also, I think a subselect should start with the keyword `select`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction. That was indeed the problem why the application could not start. Now it actually starts and queries are getting executed as well. Now my junit tests fail because of the subselect methods. If i comment them out, they work again. I edited my post with code and stacktrace.

Comment: Please do not change the main question. Accept and upvote correct/helpful answers and open a new question. Otherwise, nobody stumbling on this will be able to understand what is going on.

Comment: Oh, alright. I'll do that and remove my edits again. Thanks a lot.